# JS - jQuery.fn.DataTable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use datatables to display a list of records in two different pages. 
Problem is the first datatable works while the second one (that's a perfect clone of the first) doesn't... 
The issue is related to $.fn.DataTable: in the first case it exists so the script goes on filling the datatable while in the second case it is undefined. 
The "big" problem here is that both the datatables are perfectly the same. What changes are the ids and the content... 
These are the two scripts I'm using to populate the datatables:

```
transactionsHistoryInit : function($) {
    var datatable = $('#transactions-history-table');
    if (datatable.length > 0 && typeof $.fn.DataTable !== "undefined") {
        datatable.DataTable({
            "responsive" : true,
            "searching" : false,
            "processing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            "pageLength" : 20,
            "lengthChange" : false,
            "stateSave" : true,
            "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
            "info" : false,
            "columnDefs" : [ {
                "orderable" : false,
                "targets" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
            } ],
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : siteData.ajaxurl + "?action=transactions_history",
                "type" : 'POST'
            },
            "language" : {
                "url" : siteData.ajaxurl
                        + "?action=datatable_internazionalization"
            }
        });

        transactionStartDate.datetimepicker({
            "locale" : transactionStartDate.data("locale")
        });
        transactionEndDate.datetimepicker({
            "locale" : transactionEndDate.data("locale"),
            "defaultDate" : new Date()
        });


        transactionStartDate.add(transactionEndDate).on("dp.change",
                function(e) {
                    datatable.draw();
                });
    }
},

bankToBankAccountChoice : function($) {
    var datatable = $('#bank-account-table');
    if (datatable.length > 0 && typeof $.fn.DataTable !== "undefined") {
        datatable.DataTable({
            "responsive" : true,
            "searching" : false,
            "processing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            "pageLength" : 10,
            "lengthChange" : false,
            "stateSave" : true,
            "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
            "info" : false,
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : siteData.ajaxurl
                        + "?action=bank_to_bank_account_choice",
                "type" : 'POST'
            },
            "language" : {
                "url" : siteData.ajaxurl
                        + "?action=datatable_internazionalization"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Show place where you executes these functions, I think in this part of code is no answer at youre question.

Comment: @Zydnar they're executed every time a page is loaded

Comment: In Chrome in sources you have watch section - assign this undefined variable to global and watch when it becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting $.fn.dataTable as undefined

In my case, I was loading jquery multiple times. Jquery must be loaded only once.